# Comparing 3 lists in Python

Tags: python, list, compare

The following code compares three lists, `motherList fatherlist` and `sonList`, checking to see if every value in `sonList` is represented in either `motherList` or `fatherList` once.

```
def compareList(motherList, fatherList, sonList):
    count = 0
    for x in sonList:
            if x in motherList and x in fatherList:
                    count = 2
            elif x in motherList or x in fatherList:
                    count += 1
    if count >= 2:
            ans = "Mendelion"
    else:
            ans = "Non-Medelian"

    print"{0} {1} \t {2} \t {3}".format(motherList, fatherList, sonList, ans)
```

Outputting:

```
['0']        ['0']         ['4']         Non-Mendelion
['2', '6']   ['0']         ['0', '2']    Mendelion
['1']        ['0']         ['1']         Non-Medelian
['-1', '2']  ['-4', '-1']  ['-4', '2']   Mendelion
```

Is there a neater way to accomplish this?
Perhaps through recursive or non recursive means

Comment: Since your question is about code improvement and involves working code, you may have better luck on Code Review, but be sure to review that [site's help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure your question is appropriate

Comment: do you mean once or more or once exactly?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham At lest once

Comment: well sets are definitely the way to go. You should check out the docs there are methods like `set.symmetric_difference` that can take any iterable as an argument so you won't have to make sets out of all you lists. Using `^ &` etc. you must convert all to sets first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, it might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use sets, my friend.

```
In [1]: {0, 1, 2} & {1, 2, 3} & {2, 3, 4}
Out[1]: set([2])
```

So your code will look like:

```
if set(motherList) & set(fatherlist) & set(sonList):
    ans = "Mendelion"
else:
    ans = "Non-Medelian"
```

First of, it looks really-really good for any developer, secondly it is not so expensive, but depends on data sizes.

Sets is a special type in python, which gives you ability to find intersections(which values are in both sets) and differences, which is soo handy to use in many-many situations.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a set operation. Python sets already enforce the condition that all items are unique, and you can do things like this:

```
child_set <= (mother_set ^ father_set)
```

which creates a set of the symmetric difference between the mother and father sets (all items that are in one or the other but not both), and then tests that every item in child set is in that set.

Further reading: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension:

```
def compareList(motherList, fatherList, sonList):
    return len([i for i in sonList if i in motherList or i in fatherList])==len(sonList)
```